# How to show full command line of all processes in Windows

Tags: windows, process, cmd.exe

On Windows, in the Task Manager it is possible to see the command line of each processes but it is truncated.

How can I see the complete command line of each running process?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In cmd, run the following:

```
wmic process get processid,commandline
```

To filter for a particular program:

```
wmic process where "name like '%chrome%'" get processid,commandline
```

*Note:* This generally does not require Administrator privileges - however, you will need Administrator privileges to view the full information for processes not running under your user account.

The other properties that you can query for processes are:

- Caption
- CommandLine
- CreationClassName
- CreationDate
- CSCreationClassName
- CSName
- Description
- ExecutablePath
- ExecutionState
- Handle
- HandleCount
- InstallDate
- KernelModeTime
- MaximumWorkingSetSize
- MinimumWorkingSetSize
- Name
- OSCreationClassName
- OSName
- OtherOperationCount
- OtherTransferCount
- PageFaults
- PageFileUsage
- ParentProcessId
- PeakPageFileUsage
- PeakVirtualSize
- PeakWorkingSetSize
- Priority
- PrivatePageCount
- ProcessId
- QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage
- QuotaPagedPoolUsage
- QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage
- QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage
- ReadOperationCount
- ReadTransferCount
- SessionId
- Status
- TerminationDate
- ThreadCount
- UserModeTime
- VirtualSize
- WindowsVersion
- WorkingSetSize
- WriteOperationCount
- WriteTransferCount

Comment: NICE!!!  I love WMIC.  It's what a whole lot of expensive 3rd party stuff is based on.  Thanks a ton for taking the time to post both the question and a great complete answer.

Comment: Need to run command prompt as Administrator to view CommandLine of all processes. For e.g. CommandLine or ExecutablePath is not displayed for java.exe in non-admin run command prompt.

Comment: And if you want to filter out the "current command" i.e. the wmic command you are running, use:
`wmic process where "name like '%chrome%' and not Caption='wmic.exe'" get processid,commandline`

Comment: Require "Run as adminsitrator"

Comment: @Vinh it does not require you to launch cmd with "Run as administrator", I just tried. It might however require an account with certain privileges but doesn't require administrator.

Comment: @ontherocks: You may need Administrator to view processes running under different user accounts. Edited to add.

Answer (score 3):

> [`The WMIC tool is deprecated in Windows 10, version 21H1 and the 21H1 semi-annual channel release of Windows Server. This tool is superseded by Windows PowerShell for WMI.`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features)

Now we can use PowerShell command to achieve this:

`Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name LIKE '%OmniSharp.exe%'" | Select ProcessId, CommandLine | format-list`

or

`Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE name LIKE '%OmniSharp.exe%'" | Select ProcessId, CommandLine | format-table -wrap`

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the command line in Task Manager. You can however use a third-party task manager program like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) or [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net) to view the command line.

Open the properties dialog of the process in order to view the command line. In the case of Process Hacker, you can even add a column for the command line so that you don't have to open the properties dialogue box.

Comment: You can see the command line in Task Manager: go to View > Select Columns... and tick the box for Command Line. You can then re-organize the columns by dragging the column headers.
However, like my questions says, it is truncated if it is really long, like for java processes with long classpaths

Comment: @qwertzguy: Sorry, I must have missed that. My answer still holds though. You'll have to resort to third-party software in order to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Actually this was a question that I answered myself. I just posted it to document it for other people. You can see my answer for how to achieve the desired result without the need of third-party software.