# Running desired number of executables on Windows using batch script

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch

I have several directories (> 20) containing a Windows executable (`.EXE`) that take some input files and produce the output (`output.txt`), all in the same directory. On my Windows 10 PC (x64) having 8 CPUs, I can run all the EXEs (jobs) at the same time using the following (little and adorable) `run_jobs.bat` batch script.

```
@echo off
FOR /d /r %%i IN (*) DO (
   if exist "%%i\run_jobs.bat" start "" /d "%%i" "%comspec%" /c "run_jobs.bat"
)
```

The problem is, all the PC resources are consumed (100% usage), yielding no space for other processes. Is there a way to control/schedule the above loop such that, it runs only 7 jobs (= 7 CPUs) at the same time, keeping some resources for the other processes, until all queued executions in all directories are completed? I am open for batch or PowerShell scripting suggestions.

Comment: I don't think process scheduling can be done in a batch script (or only with complex and error prone commands and a lot of text output parsing), but you could start the processes with low priority using `start /low ...`. Doing so should restore at least basic responsiveness of the UI.

Comment: @Robert: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will try it and report back! Meanwhile, I have edited the question as I am open for both batch or PowerShell scripting suggestions.

Comment: @Robert: I replaced `start` by `start /low`, but still the 100% CPU usage.

Comment: Of course you still get 100% CPU usage, but if you look at the process priority of the 20 processes it should be "low" so other UI processes like Windows Explorer which have "normal" priority still get the necessary CPU time so you can continue to work while the processes are active in background.

Comment: If you want to limit the number of processes you could do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050611/start-multiple-tasks-in-parallel-and-wait-for-them-in-windows Of course this is not a perfect solution in case the different processes have a different execution time as you have to manually distribute them onto job tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
@echo off & setlocal

for /d /r %%i in (*)do if exist "%%~i\run_jobs.bat" call %:^) "%%~dpnxi" "run_jobs.bat"

endlocal && goto :eof

%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" (set "_path=%~1" && set "_bat=%~2")
for /f %%i in ('wmic process where "name like '%%cmd.exe%%'" get commandline ^| findstr /c:"%_bat%" ^| find /v /c ""
    ')do if %%~i leq 6 (start "" /b /d "%_path%" %comspec% /s /c "%_path%\%_bat%") else >nul (timeout 10 & goto %:^))
```

---

**1.** Send to function/label `%:ˆ)` the path to the bat file found its name.

```sh
call %:^) "%%~dpnxi" "run_jobs.bat"
```

---

**2.** When the function is called (unlike goto) it takes the arguments (`%~1` and `%~2`), and saves them in a variable for use in the `for /f` loop...

```sh
if not "%~1" == "" (set "_path=%~1" && set "_bat=%~2")
    ... for /f ... (... "%_bat%") do ...
 if ... (start ... "%_path%" ...  "%_path%\%_bat%"
    ) else (... goto %:^)
```

---

**3.** The command inside the `for /f ...(wmic|findstr|find)` loop will use redirectors to get the path of the command that started the bat with the same name passed in the argument, and it will also count how many of your bats are running...

```sh
for /f %%i in ('wmic process where "name like '%%cmd.exe%%'" get commandline ^| findstr /c:"Your_Bat_File_Name" ^| find /v /c ""
```

- **Obs.: 1** `Wmic` with filter `|findstr |Find /Count` will return number `0-7`
- **Obs: 2** For Windows 11 users, I suggest checking whether **[`Wmic`](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-wmic-command-feature-in-windows-11.5119/)** is installed or not....

---

**4.** The `if ()else` condition test the loop output, and if output in loop is less or equal than `6`, calls the current `%_bat%` to execution, otherwise wait for the `timeout 10 seconds`, and check the count again/loop output again `goto %:^)`

```sh
if %%~i leq 6 (start "" /b /d "%_path%" %comspec% /s /c "%_path%\%_bat%") else >nul (timeout 10 & goto %:^))
```

---

**5.** When it returns in the loop `goto %:ˆ)`, it checks if this time any argument was passed, as it wasn't, ignores and continues making use of the variables already defined, and if 1 or more bats have already finished, the output of this new call will be smaller and will make the bat in use in the function, be executed, or start a new wait...

```sh
if not "%~1" == "" (...) // if this time is processing redirection by goto ignore //

for /f (wmic...) do if %%~i leq 6 (
     start "%_path%\%_bat%"
   ) else ( 
     timeout 10
     goto %:^)
   )
```

---

**6.** When the `for /r /d` loop ends, the endlocal ends along with going to the End Of the File...

```sh
for /d /r ... (*)do .... // end

endlocal && goto :eof
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`Wmic /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [`For /r /d /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How to show full command line of all processes in Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1003922/969781%5D)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Thanks a lot! you rock! :)

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1726868/adding-execution-time-and-progress-bar-to-the-desired-number-of-executables-on-w). The above solution answers my current question, but doesn't automatically return to the CMD once done processing all the directories. I failed to add, e.g. the execution time to the script.

Comment: A progress bar in your bat would not be accurate, since the execution of several (simultaneous) bats can interfere with the time demand, where the number of executions of the same can have different time between them.. It would be the case to use a infinite progress bar or scaled to keep track of the number of bats run versus the bats to be executed... here is one [sample of infinite progress bar](https://superuser.com/questions/1675694/how-to-send-variable-to-a-background-process-which-is-a-loop-label-of-the-bat)

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks good. Actually, I need to find a way keep a track of batch scripting progress so far. So, it can also be an infinite progress bar without %. I will edit my follow-up question for adding time execution and infinite progress bar.

Comment: I’m here think and I’ll try help you in my next spare time...

Comment: Many thanks to you :)

Comment: @timetraveller007 I’m testing something tricks for your code on your other question, zOk?!

Comment: @lo-ol: Sounds great! Thanks a lot.. :)